# How can I remove an image in Class based UpdateView in django

Tags: python, django

I have a post update form in which I have an imagefield.
I want to know how I can remove the already selected image when I update a post so After updating the post it will not have any image.
(if I leave image input empty on update it will show the already selected image on update).
Here's image field:

```
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="{{field.html_name}}"  id="{{field.id_for_label}}">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}">Choose file</label>
    </div>
```